# How to tell a sybase jdbc dirver to exclude certain port when connecting to the sybase database server?

Tags: jdbc, sybase

My app ('App A') uses `com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver` and Spring framework 2.5.6 (for db connection pooling and ORM) to connect to a sybase 15.5 database.

For some reason, App A has used a port 34567 to talk to the sybase database server today. The port is actually reserved for another app ('App B'), and as a result App B failed (due to 'Address is already in use').

Is there anyway we can tell a jdbc driver to avoid a certain port to talk to the Sybase database server?

Comment: I suppose you use  jConnect for jdbc 7.0?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot tell the JDBC driver to exclude ports. You can tell it though what ports to use.

I suppose you use the jConnect driver. So here is a link of how you can [Invoke the jConnect driver](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc39001.0700/html/prjdbc0700/prjdbc07009.htm)

In the case that you want to set the connection properties explicitly, you can do so before connecting to the server in [two ways](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc39001.0700/html/prjdbc0700/prjdbc07009.htm):

1. Use the DriverManager.getConnection method in your application.
2. Set the connection properties when you define the URL.